# Ubuntu. Не работает touchpad

Tags: ubuntu

Привет всем. Час назад столкнулся с проблемой. Не работает touchpad или работает зависая. Но знаете в чем кроется самое интересное когда я снимаю ноутбук с зарядки то touchpad работает как новенький и реагирует на движения очень быстро. Попробовал с LiveCD та же фигня. Как исправить? Или может кто подскажет в чем дело может touchpad сломался.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, скорее всего, не в тачпаде. Тачпад наиболее критичен к колебаниям и просадкам напряжения питания. Вы не совсем корректно описали проблему - что такое "снимаю с зарядки"? Отключаю блок питания или вынимаю батарею? Перво-наперво надо проверить, кто виноват - блок питания или батарея. Попробуйте без батареи или только от батареи. Короче, ИМХО начинаются проблемы с питанием. Раза 3 с таким сталкивался - один раз вспухла одна банка батареи (проблемы с высоким зарядным током), второй - dell с неоригинальным блоком начал так себя вести. Замена на оригинальный полностью устранила проблему.

Comment: Когда работает только от своей батареи то touchpad работает. Когда подключаю кблок питания то не работает.

Comment: найдите другой, заведомо исправный блок питания и проверьте. Еще надо попробовать полностью вынуть батарею и включить только от блока питания.